# Add leading zeroes to the Minute part of a datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following csv in this format:

```
Date       Time           Dummy 
22/7/2020  11:5:49:774    123 
22/7/2020  11:5:49:868    123 
22/7/2020  11:5:50:24     123 
22/7/2020  11:5:50:196    123 
22/7/2020  11:5:50:414    123 
22/7/2020  11:5:50:730    123
```

As you can see, in the `Time` column, **a leading zero is needed for the milliseconds part**. `11:5:50.24` should optimally be converted to `11:05:50:024`. Moreover, I need to combine `Date` and `Time` into a single index column. So far here is my attempt:

```
df = pd.read_csv('...csv', parse_dates=[['Date', 'time']]) 
#parse_dates fails to parse the time column but it combines the columns Date and time so I just used it.

df["Date_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_time"], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f")
```

Everything is good except for the milliseconds part. How can I solve this?

EDIT: My apologies, I realised I need to add a leading zero to ALL UNITS of time, not just milliseconds.
E.g. `7:5:50:730` should become `07:05:50.730`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: sorry my pandas syntax was off

EDIT2: forgot that python datetime expects microseconds

Could you try something like:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", parse_dates=[["Date", "Time"]])
print(df)


def parse_time(datetime_str):
    date_str, time_str = datetime_str.split(" ")
    hour, minute, sec, msec = time_str.split(":")
    day, month, year = date_str.split("/")
    return datetime(
        int(year), int(month), int(day), int(hour), int(minute), int(sec), int(msec) * 1000
    )


df["Date_Time"] = df["Date_Time"].apply(parse_time)
print(df)
```

Initial:

```
               Date_Time  Dummy
0  22/7/2020 11:5:49:774    123
1  22/7/2020 11:5:49:868    123
2  22/7/2020 11:5:50:24     123
3  22/7/2020 11:5:50:196    123
4  22/7/2020 11:5:50:414    123
5  22/7/2020 11:5:50:730    123
```

Output:

```
                Date_Time  Dummy
0 2020-07-22 11:05:49.774    123
1 2020-07-22 11:05:49.868    123
2 2020-07-22 11:05:50.024    123
3 2020-07-22 11:05:50.196    123
4 2020-07-22 11:05:50.414    123
5 2020-07-22 11:05:50.730    123
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: From comment added logic to deal with where we need to add a leading zero to the millisecond part as well with calculating the `len` of the milliseconds part and adding a leading 0 if the len is `2` using `rsplit`.

You have to join and then manipulate the date and time fields into a format that python can read as datetime. You can do this by accessing various parts of the strings in `Time` by position with `.str[]`.

This is how you add a leading zero for the minute part:

```
df['Date'] + ' '+ df['Time'].str[0:3] + '0' +
                         df['Time'].str[3:6]
```

Also, you can't have a `:` for the milliseconds, so skip that `:` character in position 7 and add a `.` instead with `df1['Time'].str[3:6] + '.' + df1['Time'].str[8:]`. Finally, you have to pass `dayfirst=True`.

Full code:

```
df['Time'] = np.where(df['Time'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(':')[3])) == 2,
                   df['Time'].str.rsplit(':', 1).str[0] + ':0' + df['Time'].str.rsplit(':' ,1).str[1],
                  df['Time'])
df['Date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' '+ df['Time'].str[0:3] + '0' +
                             df['Time'].str[3:6] + '.' + df['Time'].str[8:], dayfirst=True)
```

output:

```
            Date        Time        Dummy   DateTime
0           22/7/2020   11:5:49:774 123     2020-07-22 11:05:04.774
1           22/7/2020   11:5:49:868 123     2020-07-22 11:05:04.868
2           22/7/2020   11:5:50:24  123     2020-07-22 11:05:05.240
3           22/7/2020   11:5:50:196 123     2020-07-22 11:05:05.196
4           22/7/2020   11:5:50:414 123     2020-07-22 11:05:05.414
5           22/7/2020   11:5:50:730 123     2020-07-22 11:05:05.730
```

Comment: I get the idea. But there should be a leading zero added if the precision is up to 2 decimal places, not a zero added to the back. So `11:5:50:24` should be `11:05:50.024`. `11:5:50:24` means 11.05 am, 50.024 seconds.

Comment: See updated answer. You could add: `df['Time'] = np.where(df['Time'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(':')[3])) == 2,
                       df['Time'].str.rsplit(':', 1).str[0] + ':0' + df['Time'].str.rsplit(':' ,1).str[1],
                      df['Time'])`